# linear gradient in IE9

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, linear-gradients

This is a linear-gradient code in Google Chrome:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#FFFF99),color-stop(25%,#FFFF99),color-stop(25%,#FFCC00),color-stop(50%,#FFCC00),color-stop(50%,#FFFF99),color-stop(75%,#FFFF99),color-stop(75%,#FFCC00), to(#FFCC00));        -
webkit-background-size: 8px;
```

How i can convert this property to IE9?

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer to my question.